# Hashtag for google not to follow link. Make the jquery request find the method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, seo, fancybox

Im making some SEO changes to our site and right now im having some problems with Fancyapps fancybox iframe. My current links look like this

`<a href="/Home/Action/Parameter" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe">Text</a>`

Google will follow and index this link/site and thats no good. I can avoid this by putting a `#` at the begining at the `href`like this

`<a href="#/Home/Action/Parameter" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe">Text</a>`

Problem then becomes that the action/method can not be found. So how can i make the fancybox.iframe call ignore the `#`, or question is can i?

If anybody feels like editing my headline please do, i just could not sum it up good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `rel="nofollow"` attribute to your links to prevent Google from following them. It's a standard, well-known way to prevent your SEO juice from *trickling* to the linked site.

```
<a href="google.com" rel="nofollow">To Google!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<a href="/Home/Action/Parameter" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" rel="nofollow">Text</a>
```

Then drop the hashtag. See http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=da&answer=96569